# Getting SQLCODE=-313 when using prepared statements DB2

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, jdbc

Currently I'm having an issue where when executing queries/inserts using prepared statement in node-jdbc, I will sometimes get an error:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-313, SQLSTATE=07004
```

When looking this error code up on IBMs website, it says:

> THE NUMBER OF HOST VARIABLES SPECIFIED IS NOT EQUAL TO THE NUMBER OF
>   PARAMETER MARKERS
>
> https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n313.dita

I've also tried removing all prepared statement and simply setting the values, doing so solved my issue but for obvious reasons I can't do that. Also, the crash doesn't happen every time, and it can happen on any of the queries that are using prepared statements.

Any help would really be really appreciated,
Rafi

Edit - Added link to dB code : http://pastebin.com/sm1nbhdi

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: Added in link, thanks.

Comment: You should include the code in the question, not only link to an external site.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is tagged as javascript, but I was running into this error in java (with db2 and eclipse link) with `NamedNativeQuery`. It was a weird issue that had to do with the param binding. I had existing named queries that used `:` for param binding, e.g. `:param` which were working fine.

The solution seem to be to change the param bind from `:` to `#`.